# PHP Codeigniter Email Class Multi-dimensional Array

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to pass the data of a multidimensional array through to an email template with Codeigniter, it loads all of the associative array information fine, but when it comes to the multi-dimensional keys/values it does not identify them.

http://pastie.org/3132406

That is the code for the core functions happening from the controllers to the views.

Comment: Are you running these queries in your view?

Comment: The only thing run in the view is the $bodyOptions explode and the getProductName function

Comment: You should never be running queries in your view. That's the point of a framework like codeigniter. You should be running queries in your model (or controller) and then passing the results to your view. In either case, what piece are you exactly having trouble with? What are you getting and what are you expecting?

Comment: I've just altered the controller and view to do all of the querying on the controller side, but now when the email is sent, none of the exploded $getBuild options are coming through to the view. Also I'm trying to explode one of the passed variables when it's in the view just to echo out a dynamic list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your $getBuild var into your view you need to make sure you are passing it to the view like this

```
function my_method() {
    $data['getBuild'] = 'something';
    $this->load->view('myView', $data);
}
```

Then in your view you can access it like this

```
<h1><?php echo $getBuild ?></h1>
```